# Making current_page_item work with wp_list_pages in sidebar on post pages

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

I'm working on a website where we have a menu in the sidebar that pulls the list of the parent for the current page, and all the children of that page.

The problem is that, on pages where there's a query for posts included, this menu doesn't work. I got around it by creating a custom menu for any pages like this, but then the `current_page_item` class does not appear. How can I fix this code to work on these odd pages? Do I need to adjust the post queries within the theme pages, or the sidebar query for the pages?

This is the normal menu query:

```
if($post->post_parent) {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&depth=1");
  $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
  }

  else {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1");
  $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
  }
  if ($children) { ?>

  <h6> <?php echo $titlenamer; ?> </h6>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
```

And this is the adjusted code that I tried using that does not display the `current_page_item` class in:

```
  if($post->post_parent) {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=11&echo=0&depth=1");
  $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
  }

  else {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=11&echo=0&depth=1");
  $titlenamer = get_the_title(11);
  }
  if ($children) { ?>

  <h6> <?php echo $titlenamer; ?> </h6>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after you run any extra queries, and before you output your menu.

Comment: It's crazy. I had tried that before, but I never got it to work. Then I realized that I should have tried `wp_reset_query()`, and of course that worked because it's using `query_posts`. Maybe I'm pushing my luck now, but I should ask - for story post pages, where I still want that sidebar menu to appear, is there a way of still having that `current_page_item` set for the one page item? Of even just telling it, like in the second code example above which parent and then which child to use as current?

Comment: `wp_reset_query` also itself calls `wp_reset_postdata`, but for extra queries you should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and not `query_posts`. [See this question for info on why](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "story post pages"?

Comment: Sorry. So, the page where I had this issue had a query for posts. When the user clicks through, they're going to the single template, which means I can't use the same sidebar there, but I want the same menu to appear there without hardcoding it in. Does that help?

Comment: how would you know what page the user came from to be able to display the correct menu? you'd have to somehow pass that information from the originating page to the target page, like maybe appending something on the URL like `?source=n`, where `n` is the ID of the page you came from. you'd then have to check if `$_GET['source']` is set and show the appropriate menu that way. but then you'd have to output the menu manually to set the proper classes. a somewhat involved process!

Comment: Yeah, good point. I'll see if I can find a simpler method instead. Thanks!